# Okta SAML 2.0 implementation in Spring MVC (Not Spring boot)

Tags: spring-mvc, saml, saml-2.0, okta, spring-saml

Is there any sample web application code implemented in spring MVC and authenticated through Okta Saml? All over the internet has everything about springboot - okta example :( I don't find any sample example project for vanilla Spring MVC (not boot application).

Comment: You might try this documentation: https://developer.okta.com/code/java/spring_security_saml/

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in using Okta or any other SAML Identity Provider implementation. You may just follow the example in Spring Security SAML and use the IdP meta data of your Okta-based IdP instead.